# Selecting Columns without Header

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am currently making a simple e-mail list to be used by my office for e-mail blasts. I want to have the first row a header (I currently have the first row frozen) and that whenever you click on a column to select it (like clicking on column 'C') it will automatically select everything except the header/first row.

How do I set up the worksheet to always do this?

Answer (score 3):

One possible way (applied to columns A to E only):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim lrow As Long
Dim sCol As Long
sCol = Target.Column

If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("A:E")) Is Nothing Then
    If Intersect(Target, Columns(sCol)).Address = Columns(sCol).Address Then
        lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, Target.Column()).End(xlUp).Row
        Range(Cells(2, Target.Column()), Cells(lrow, Target.Column())).Select
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

If you select the whole column, the selection will change to row 2 down to the last populated row. If you select a single cell in the column, nothing happens.

To apply this, right-click the sheet tab, select "View Code" and paste the code into the big white code area of the Visual Basic Editor. Close the VBE. Remember to save the workbook as a macro-enabled file if you run Excel 2007 or later.